# Krull Dimension of Affine Curve / Transcendence Degree of Coordinate Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, krull-dimension, transcendence-degree

I am trying to prove that the Krull dimension of an irreducible affine curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$ is 1. So my idea is a prove that the dimension of the coordinate ring is 1. So if the coordinate ring is

$$R = F[X,Y]/(f)$$ where $(f)$ is the irreducible polynomial in $F[X,Y]$ whose zero locus is the points on our irreducible affine curve. Now to show this has Krull dim 1, I was going to use prove that the transcendence degree of $R$ over $F$ is 1. I broke this into two cases:

Case 1: f is a polynomial of a single variable (say $Y$), then **I am not sure if the following is correct** but I think I can say that then
$R \simeq F[X]$, and thus the transcendence degree of $R$ over $F$ is 1.

Case 2: f is a polynomial in two variables. Then I am thinking that I can say the transcendence degree of R over F is 1, if $[X] \in R$ is algebraically independent over $F$. **This I am having trouble with, I think the idea is to prove that the homeomorphism $F[X] \to R$ that maps $X \to [X]$ is injective?**
And we also need to show that the fraction field $Frac(R)$ is algebraic over $F(X)$. Which I guess follows from the fact that $F$ is an algebraically closed field?

I'm wondering if somebody can point me in the right direction, or perhaps there is another way to look at this problem? I am not that comfortable with transcendence degree.

Comment: If necessary swap $X,Y$. Then  $f$ is non constant in $Y$ so that $Y\in R$ is algebraic over $F[X]\subset R$. It remains to check that the subring $F[X]\subset R$ is just the polynomial ring $F[X]$.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused by your comment, do you mean this for my first case? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I presume that you assume $F$ is algebraically closed. In which case, your first case is correct as then $f \in F[y]$ is irreducible, hence linear as $F$ is algebraically closed. Thus, you will get $R \cong F[x]$. If $F = \mathbb R$ then take for instance $f = y^2 + 1$. Then $R \cong \mathbb C[x]$, not $\mathbb R[x]$.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read far enough to where you did specify that explicitly.